# Issue in firestore database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I want to show current user data in my flutter app. But it print on screen " No data found".
This my database data

[image]

That error also happened error

[image]

My security rule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8ba.png)

Here is my code

```
 Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
             stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user3").where("id",isEqualTo:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                   if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return Text("Loading please wait........");
                   }
                   if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.length > 0) {
                     DocumentSnapshot userData = snapshot.data!.docs[0];
                     // Build the widget using the userData
                   } else {
                     return Center(child: Text("No data found"));
                   }
return Container();
           
                   },
                ),
          ),
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a current user logged in at this point in your code? From your error messages it does not look like it. Check if your "FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser" is logged in. 

I have just been sitting with similar code the last couple of days and you could do something like this after your "where("id", isEualTo)..") to check if that is where you have a error:
snapshot, error in if error != nil {
                            print(error!.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        }

Comment: Yes current user is logged.And also when i want print data in console it show empty array. Can you solve error by specific code?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content such as error messages and security rules. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The long numeric values (e.g. `"167582..."`) in your database screenshot do not look like a UID that any of the Firebase Authentication providers would generate.

Add this code right before you query the database:

```
print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
```

This will show you the value that you're querying for, which (given my opening statement) probably looks quite different from the value in your database.

If that is indeed the case, the problem starts when you **write** the document. At that point you'll want to make sure that you write the value of `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid` to the `id` field.

Comment: Yes you are right this is not uid this is id that i generate then please tell how i store uid in database and also how i retrieve please...Thanks in andvance

Comment: Sorry, but that seems like a different, follow-up question. Your original question was why the query doesn't work, which is what I explained in my answer here. To solve this issue you'll want to make sure that you write the value of `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid` to the `id` field, rather than (or in addition to) the timestamp-like value you currently have. If you need help getting that to work, I recommend opening a new question showing how you current write the user document. ---